# I get this error when I try to insert data in MySQL using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

A PHP error was encountered:

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: My_sales::$db
>
> Filename: core/Model.php
>
> Line Number: 51
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function insert() on a non-object in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Learning_CI/application/models/sales.php on line 10

Comment: That's a nice error message. Does it come with any code...?

Comment: Please post the relevant portion of `application/models/sales.php`

Comment: Please post relevent portion of code.It would be helpful to solve

Comment: sales.php    <?php
class Sales extends CI_Model
{
/*This is to insert data on database*/
  public function insert_sale($data)
  {
     /*array('field'=>$this->input->post('name of your input form field'))*/


   $this->db->insert('sales_table',$data);
   return $data;
  }

  /*Display your current sales you inserted */
  public function get_sales()
  {
   $query= $this->db->get('sales_table');
  /*Check if there are rows returned*/
  if($query->num_rows()> 0){
  /*assign the result in a data array*/
   foreach($query->result() as $row) 
   {
    $data[] = $row;
   }
   return $data;
  }
}

}?>

Comment: Please edit your question and add code there. It's difficult to read as a comment. When editing, remember to properly format your question.

Comment: ok i will send my code in question

Answer (score 1):

Based on your error message it looks like your database driver is not loaded. Make sure that you load the database class before attempting to use it in a model by using the following function.

```
$this->load->database();
```

You can either do this in the function itself, or in the model constructor.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}
```

Alternatively if you want to use the database across the entire site, add it to `application/config/autoload.php` by adding it to the following line of that file:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database' /* other auto-loaded libraries */);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should load database library in order to use $this->db->insert();

```
this->load->library('database');
```

You can load in application->config->autoload-> load libraries. or in the constructor of specific model or even in the just one line above the '$this->db'.